# Disable manually built urls for dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase Dynamic Links has a feature to build custom URLs manually: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

Let's say I connected `example.com` to Dynamic links and use it by creating custom links for youtube livestreams, among other things.

This means that I had to allowlist youtube.com as a destination for the short urls.

This means any user could create a custom link `example.com/?link=http://youtube.com/scam-video` and share it. Since people trust my domain example.com, this is a serious phishing issue.

**Is there a way to disable this feature?** There is an API I use to create the URLs I need on the fly, it makes no sense (to me) to allow anyone without authentication to be creating valid URLs with my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing this with the Google's Firebase team I have an official answer and no, it is not supported nor is there an intention to add support for disabling custom URLs in the short term at least.

Only workaround is to use as strict allowlist rules as possible, you can use regex which helps.